# Swift - Storyboard Table View Controller Scrollable Content Size Ambiguity

Tags: xcode, storyboard, swift, constraints, autolayout

If I start a new Swift Project, create a new Storyboard, drag a navigation Controller to the Storyboard it keeps coming up with layout errors saying Scrollable Content Size Ambiguity - Has ambiguous scrollable content width.

If I click the "pin" icon to try and add constraints its all greyed out.

Surely this shouldn't be happening?

Does anyone know a fix / work around or what I am doing wrong?

Many Thanks,

Krivvenz.

Comment: I think this is a beta issue - raise a bug report with Apple.

Comment: I filed a similar radar, about Table View cells (17621035)

Comment: yeah I see this too in beta 3 but not beta 2..

Comment: Have the same issue with UICollectionViews

Comment: In Xcode 6.3 beta there seems to be no issues with this. :)